# Looping a fork()

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, fork, pid

This is a sample of my code for some piping I want to do. The problem is that pid2[0] does not supply me a child process.  How do I fix it?  pid2[1] and pid2[2] and so on do supply the parent with children.

```
int numCommands = numPipes + 1;      /// not worrying about '>' and '<' right now
int *pipes = newint[numPipes*2];     /// two ends for each pipe
for(int i = 0; i < numPipes*2; i+=2) /// Offset by two since each pipe has two ends
   pipe(pipes + i);
int *pid2 = new int [numCommands];

for(int i = 0; i < numCommands; i++)
{
   pid2[i] = fork();
   if(pid2[i] < 0)   
   {
      std::cerr << "Failure to fork..." << std:endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE
   }

   if(pid2[i] == 0)    /// Child process
   {
      if(i == 0)       /// First Command
      {
         dup2(pipes[1], 1);
      }

      else if(i == numCommands -1)  /// Last Command
      {
         dup2(pipes[2*(numCommands-1)-1], 0);
      }

      else             /// Middle commands
      {
         dup2(pipes[2*(i-1)], 0);    
         dup2(pipes[(2*i)+1],1);
      }
      for(int j = 0; j < numPipes*2;j++)
         close(pipes[j]);
      execvp(pipeCommands[i][0], pipeCommands[i].data());  ///pipeCommands is a vector<vector<char*>>
      perror("exec failed");
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   else        /// The parent
   {
      for(int j = 0; j <numPipes*2;j++)
          close(pipes[j]);
      for(int k = 0; k < numCommands; k++)
         waitpid(pid2[k],nullptr,0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Show your real code, you waste everyone's time by posting fake code.

Comment: @LeifChipman Given the new code you posted, what is the error?

Comment: Same as in the question.  The first command in a string doesn't make it to exec or dup2, but the commands following the first make it.  From some debugging I think it's because pid2[0] doesn't return a zero.

Comment: @LeifChipman: That's nonsense. If `fork()` doesn't fail, which you check for, then it will definitely return `0` in one process and a process ID in the other. Your problem is somewhere else. You don't check whether *any* of your calls to `dup2()` or `close()` fail, which is an obvious problem. You're also writing spaghetti code and misusing arrays which is really where the fundamental problem lies - you are making your code too hard for you to understand. It's crying out to be broken into more functions and for some structure to be given to your data.

Comment: @LeifChipman How do you know that the first command isn't making it to dup2/exec?

Comment: I added `std::cout << " This is the command " << pipeCommands[i][0] << " for i: " << i << std::endl;` above exec.     Then tested it with input `sort file.txt | head | wc` I get results for head for i: 1 and wc for i: 2, but not sort.   Sorry for the format in the comment, not sure how to grey it like code.

Comment: @LeifChipman You surround the text in back ticks (`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexing into the `pipes` array is a little bit problematic. For `sort file.txt | head | wc` I'm assuming that numPipes is 2. Let's walk through your for loop for each value of `i`.

i==0

```
dup2(pipes[1], 1); // Send stdout to pipes[1]
```

i==1

```
dup2(pipes[2*(i-1)], 0); // dup2(pipes[0], 0), stdin from pipes[0]
dup2(pipes[(2*i)+1],1);  // dup2(pipes[3], 1), stdout to pipes[3]
```

i == 2

```
dup2(pipes[2*(numCommands-1)-1], 0); //dup2(pipes[3], stdin from pipes[3]
```

In other words, any stdout from process 0 is going to a dead end. The second process will never read from its standard output. So the debug statement you put in there (cout == stdout, remember) will get lost as well.

Comment: I highly doubt this is the problem, since it won't even compile with that line as written.

Comment: I need it inside the loop so I can fork an arbitrary number of child processes.

Comment: @LeifChipman If you're trying to use it to keep track of the pids, it will go out of scope after the for loop exits an you'll have lost that information. If the parent process blocks until the child is finished you don't need an array, a single pid_t will do.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, that's the problem.  Can you show how you would modify the indexing?

Comment: @LeifChipman I would make a true 2-D array for your pipes. That way you can index it much easier. For example `pipes[i][0]` and `pipes[i][1]`. The first index is the pipe number, the second is the read or write end of the pipe. Also, you should be more selective about the loops that close the pipes. Only close the ones you don't need instead of all of them.